# Perl Net::SFTP known_hosts2 permission denied

Tags: perl, ssh, ftp, sftp

I wrote a simple test script to connect to an ftp server and list the files on that host.
The script works with normal FTP, but the secure version fails because it cannot access/write a certain file:

```
/w/megaman/.ssh/known_hosts2: Permission denied at /global/apps/sun4/5.x/pkgs/perl-5.8.4/lib/site_perl/5.8.4/Net/SSH/Perl.pm line 372
```

Should I `chmod` that file? Or, what could be the simplest workaround?

Comment: please add the output of `ls -ld ~/.ssh/known*`

Comment: @michas I'll try to set write permissions.. it doesn't have them. I'll update the question afterwards (might take a while since I can't access the machine for the next hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sftp basically starts a normal ssh connection.

ssh knows about both `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and `~/.ssh/known_hosts2` and tries to read them if they exist.

Did you try to make a backup of `known_hosts` and named it maybe `known_hosts2`? - Removing known_hosts2 should do the trick, as it is usually not used at all.

Also have a look at your `/global/apps/sun4/5.x/pkgs/perl-5.8.4/lib/site_perl/5.8.4/Net/SSH/Perl.pm` line 372 as indicated in the error. What is it trying to do? reading that known_host2?

Comment: I'll back it up, then delete it. But first I'll try the `chmod`.. thanks for the hints!!